# How to store arraylist in global variable and call it in another request

Tags: postman

My current Response is in arraylist

“pinvalues”:
[
1,
3
]

i want to store this 2 value in global variable then i need to call this in another request like below.

Request

pinposition":
[
1,
3
]

how can i achieve it,Any suggestion , Advance thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your first request in Tests scripts, you can parse and save the array as a string:

```js
const response = pm.response.json();

pm.environment.set('pinvalues', JSON.stringify(response.pinvalues));
```

[image]

In your another request, you set the following body:

```json
{
    "pinposition": {{pinvalues}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried the same way, while calling the global variable   pm.global.get('pinvalue') same name i created global variable. i can see the console log, the value not able to pick from the env variable ..0

Comment: You can't use `pm.global.get('pinvalue')` outside Pre-req. and Tests scripts. Plus I recommend using `pm.variables.get()` since that looks at more places for the variable.

Comment: in 1st request test :  var jsonData =JSON.parse(responseBODY); pm.environment.set("pinposition",jsonData["pinpositions"];   console.log(jsonData.[ "pinpositions"]);   using above query in 1st request i can see arry list printing in console.          and in 2nd request  i mentined in request as "{{pinpositions}}" then in the test i mentioned it as pm.variable.get("pinPositions"); this is my env variable name but getting failed in 2nd requestbgetting null value showing in console, not sure  where i did wrong..please suggest

Comment: @prem: Why don't you just copy what I answered? `var jsonData =JSON.parse(responseBODY);` will result in `ReferenceError: responseBODY is not defined` because `jsonBODY` is a name that is not defined (unless you left out some code in your comment. Then you set `pinposition` but refer to it with `pinpositions`, obviously these are two different names. Then you also write `pinPositions`, that's a different case, JS is case sensitive.